# Creating filterable search

Tags: jquery, search, filter

I was wondering if anyone has any examples or tutorials on how I can create a search area like the one on BuySellAds.com to the left of [this page](http://buysellads.com/buy).

I like the sliders and how you can select a category and it will automatically update.

Also, can this be done with jQuery?

thanks for any help/info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), a library with user interface widgets, has a [slider you can specify such a range with](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range). Having that range you then can make an [Ajax request](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) to get the search results and show them in your document.